# uniq returns other result than uniq_by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Until now I used `uniq_by` to count unique projectusers. But this method has been deprecated and the suggestion is to use `uniq` instead. But `uniq_by` returns 2 (correct!) and `uniq` returns 3 (not correct). The projectuser table is filled like this:

```
id,user_id
1,1
2,1
3,2
```

And here are the statements:

```
Projectuser.uniq_by {|p| p.user_id}.count --> 2
Projectuser.uniq {|p| p.user_id}.count --> 3
```

What do I need to change?

Comment: First of all, you should not use any of those methods, as those are defined for an array, however problem seems to be quite weird. What ruby version are you using?

Comment: version of ruby is 2.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result is rigth, since `uniq` is from Array. To match the uniqueness in SQL idiom you need to use distinct.

From the example from the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-distinct):

```
person.pets.select(:name).distinct
# => [#<Pet name: "Fancy-Fancy">]
```

Try:

```
Projectuser.select(:id, :user_id).distinct
```

Answer (score 1):

The ActiveReord-Version of uniq seem to ignore the given block, and just check that the objects are uniq. If you look at the source you see that is just sets a flag.

See
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/uniq

You can think of it as a modifier for the generated sql-statement.

Answer (score 0):

I have it solved by using:

```
Projectuser.uniq.pluck(:user_id)
```